# Trigonometry for checking to see if facing building

Tags: java, android, camera, opengl-es-2.0, trigonometry

I am trying to see if my camera is facing a building.

I use `xDelta` and `zDelta` when moving the camera along the place

`xDelta=sine/4` and `zDelta=cosine/4` (to limit speed of movement).

Basically, my idea is to take the distance of the building, and apply the deltas scaled to the distance of the building to the camera's coordinates to get a set of projected coordinates.  I then try to take the distance between the building coordinates and the projected coordinates to see if the camera is facing it.

I can confirm that the distances to the building are correct, however, I think there is a problem with the projection coordinates. This is my code so far:

```
    building1Distance = Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_X - BUILDING1_X), 2) + Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_Z - BUILDING1_Z), 2);
    building1Distance = Math.sqrt(building1Distance);

    building2Distance = Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_X - BUILDING2_X), 2) + Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_Z - BUILDING2_Z), 2);
    building2Distance = Math.sqrt(building2Distance);

    building3Distance = Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_X - BUILDING3_X), 2) + Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_Z - BUILDING3_Z), 2);
    building3Distance = Math.sqrt(building3Distance);

    building4Distance = Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_X - BUILDING4_X), 2) + Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_Z - BUILDING4_Z), 2);
    building4Distance = Math.sqrt(building4Distance);

    //sort them
    distances = new double[4];
    distances[0] = building1Distance;
    distances[1] = building2Distance;
    distances[2] = building3Distance;
    distances[3] = building4Distance;
    Arrays.sort(distances);

    //search to see if pointing at building
    for(int i = 0; i < distances.length; i++){
        //projected coordinates of where camera is facing at that distance
        pX = CAMERA_X + (xDelta * 4.0 * distances[i]);
        pZ = CAMERA_Z + (zDelta * 4.0 * distances[i]);

        //check to see which building is at that distance
        if(building1Distance == distances[i]){
            //check to see if its within diameter of the building.
            if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_X - pX), 2) + Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_Z - pZ), 2)) < 50){
                buildingIndex = 1;
                return;
            }

        }else if(building2Distance == distances[i]){
            if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_X - pX), 2) + Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_Z - pZ), 2)) < 30){
                buildingIndex = 2;
                return;
            }
        }else if(building3Distance == distances[i]){
            if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_X - pX), 2) + Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_Z - pZ), 2)) < 50){
                buildingIndex = 3;
                return;
            }
        }else{
            if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_X - pX), 2) + Math.pow((double)(CAMERA_Z - pZ), 2)) < 10){
                buildingIndex = 4;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    buildingIndex = -1;
```

It seems to be always setting `buildingIndex` to `-1`.

It's not easy to debug because I am making a Google Cardboard application, and to move in my world I must unplug the USB and plug in a keyboard (I don't have a bluetooth one).

Can anyone see a problem in my logic/code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your threshold logic is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using CAMERA_X and CAMERA_Z instead of the building's coordinates when testing how far the projected point was.